# expanding a jpeg file's 'pixel' size without increasing the file size?

Tags: jpeg, expansion

I'm curating a web site (joomla, as it happens) and I notice that every (jpeg) image file uploaded is stored in a series of 'sizes', of which the largest is~ 25 times the original size. (9k -> 240k) - just to support display to a larger 'view port', I assume.  Is there any practical way, either with jpeg transfoms, other common web image formats or any other wacky idea, to build image files with larger pixel dimensions but retaining approximately the same file size as the original?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply resize the images with CSS/HTML? If you simply resize them without any quality improvement, you are wasting bandwidth by sending the bigger image.

If you are looking to generate lower resolution thumbnails from a single large image, use [JPEGMini](http://www.jpegmini.com/). Alternatively, Photoshop has an excellent "Save for web and devices" feature that dramatically reduces the size of images with customizable loss.

Comment: Resizing with css is not an option because the insertion of the images (hrefs) into joomla webpages is done automatically by code fragments all through joomla and any extensions that may be in use on a given site.
The specific point I am interested in is, given that the expanded file at 240k contains no more 'data' than the 9k original, if there is a way to use 'jpeg magic' to represent the larger canvas with a similar small amount of data, without loss of resolution...

Comment: If you know which image to get, then you know which size you need. Why not use the width and height attributes of the img tag to correctly size that image?